# mongoexport convert numeric value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I'm trying to export phone numbers from a collection. Below is the sample document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5cf864717256ff02b4923"),"userName":"9619324746", "firstName" : "D H", "contactPhone" : 9619324746}
```

The export command that I used is below

```
mongoexport --db dbname --collection accounts --type=json --out accounts.json --fields contactPhone,userName
```

And the contents of JSON looks like below

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ad5cf864717256ff02b4923"},"userName":"9619324746","contactPhone":9.619324746e+09}
```

Can somebody help me to get the contactPhone value not converted? Thank you.

-Srini

Answer (score 0):

If mongoexport exported 123 as 123.0, then 123 was a Double type in the document. You should try inserting the value as a 32- or 64-bit integer

```
db.collection.insert({
    "tweetId" : NumberLong(1234567)
})
```

***mongoexport*** exports JSON, using strict mode JSON representation, which inserts some type information into the JSON so MongoDB JSON parsers (like mongoimport) can reproduce the correct BSON data types while the exported JSON still conforms to the JSON standard

```
{ "tweetId" : { "$numberLong" : "1234567" } }
```

To preserve all the type information, use mongodump/mongorestore instead. To export all field values as strings, you'll need to write your own script with a driver that fetches each doc and stringifies all the values.